# The optimization problem of pulse signal filtering using Kalman filter

Tags: filters, kalman-filters

I'm trying to use a Kalman filter to process a pulse signal. My model is:

x= [x1,x2]$^T$

System model:
X$_k$ = x$_{k-1}$ + W$_{k-1}$ , so A = I$_{2×2}$, the identity matrix.
and  Q=

$$
\begin{matrix}
q_{1} &  0  \\
0  &  q_{2} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Measurement model:
We will incorporate the time dependence of the signal into the measurement. At time t$_{k}$ we measure the scalar quantity:
$$
     Z_{k}=x_{1,k}×g(t_{k}) + x_{2,k} + v_{k}
$$

and thus H=[g 1] (g represents g(t),
g(t) is the time dependence of the signal(when there is a signal, g(t)=1, else g(t) = 0(background)), R = E[vv$^T$]=r, a scalar.

and recursion relations are as follows:
$$
P_{k}^{'} = p_{k-1} + Q
$$

letP$_{k}$$^{'}$ =

$$
\begin{matrix}
p_{11}^{'} &  p_{12}^{'}  \\
p_{21}^{'} &  p_{22}^{'} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

and K$_{k}$=

$$
K_{k} = 1/D×[g(P_{11}+q_{1} + P_{12}, gP_{21} + P_{22} +q_{2}]^{T} = [K_{1} ,K_{2}]^{T}
$$

Where:
$$
D=g^{2}P_{11}^{'} + g(P_{12}^{'}+P_{21}^{'})+P_{22}^{'}+r
$$

The estimate of the state vector is:
$$
x_{1,k}=x_{1,k-1}(1-gk_{1})+k_{1}(Z_{K}-X_{2,K-1})\\
x_{2,k}=x_{2,k-1}(1-k_{2})+k_{2}(Z_{K}-gX_{1,K-1})
$$

The update error covariance P$_{k}$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
1- g×K_{1}* P_{11}^{'}- K_{1}×P_{21}^{'}&  1- g×K_{1}* P_{12}^{'}- K_{1}×P_{22}^{'}  \\
-g× * K_{2} *P_{11}^{'} + (1-K_{2}) × P_{21}^{'} & -g× * K_{2} *P_{12}^{'} + (1-K_{2}) × P_{22}^{'} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

The reason for choosing the Kalman filter is that it is mentioned that filtering noise with Kalman filter can effectively extract the signal that is buried in noise.

```
% square wave

clear
clc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
create simulation wave
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
num = 8000;
t = 1:num;
Z = square(t/500,20);    
Z = Z+1.4;
Z = Z*2;              
Z0 = Z;                  % original y data

Z = smooth(Z,100,'rlowess');    % add rise and droop of the square wave

signal1 = Z(700:3810);  
% plot(signal1);

x_damp=0:0.01:4*pi;
y_damp=exp(-0.5*x_damp);
y_damp_1=y_damp.*sin(2*x_damp);

signal2 = y_damp_1(150:600) * 20 +10;

% figure(2)
% plot(signal2)

signal1 = signal1'; 

% sim_y = [signal1 signal2];
sim_y = signal1;

% figure(3)
% plot(sim_y)

% 4 waves
sim_y_last = [sim_y sim_y];
sim_y_last = [sim_y_last sim_y];
sim_y_last = [sim_y_last sim_y];
sim_y_last = [sim_y_last sim_y];
sim_y_last = [sim_y_last sim_y];

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

figure
plot(sim_y_last,'LineWidth',2 );   
legend('sim_y_last_origin')

% gauss noise
noise = normrnd(0,1,[1,length(sim_y_last)]); 
noise = noise * 0.5;

sim_y_last = sim_y_last + noise;

figure(4)

plot(sim_y_last)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% g(i) of the time dependent square wave
num = length(sim_y_last);
g=1:length(sim_y_last);
for i=1:length(sim_y_last)
    if (sim_y_last(i) > 1.5)
        g(i) = 1;
    else
        g(i) = 0;
    end
end


data_x1 = zeros(1,num);
data_x2 = zeros(1,num);
data_kg = zeros(1,num);
data_p11 = zeros(1,num);

x = 1:num;                  % x   
drive = 0;

q1 = 0.1;         %0.1
q2 = 0.1;       %0.1
r = 10;          %100


n = q1 + q2 + r;

P_k_11 = n/2;
P_k_12 = 0;
P_k_21 = 0;
P_k_22 = n/2;

x_1_k = 0;
x_2_k = 0;

K_k_1 = 0;
K_k_2 = 1;

for i=1:num

    %  X_ = X_last;
    x_1_k_ = x_1_k;
    x_2_k_ =         x_2_k;
    
    %  P_ = P_last +Q;
    P_k_pie_11 = P_k_11                            + q1;
    P_k_pie_12 =          P_k_12;
    P_k_pie_21 =                   P_k_21;
    P_k_pie_22 =                            P_k_22 + q2;
    
    % Kg = P_/(P_+R);
    D = g(i) * g(i) * P_k_pie_11 + g(i) * (P_k_pie_12 + P_k_pie_21) + P_k_pie_22 + r;
    
    K_k_1 =  1/D * (g(i) * P_k_pie_11 + P_k_pie_12);
    K_k_2 =  1/D * (g(i) * P_k_pie_21 + P_k_pie_22);
    
    %  X = X_+Kg*(Z(i) + drive -X_);   
    x_1_k = x_1_k_ * (1-g(i) * K_k_1) + K_k_1 *(sim_y_last(i) -        x_2_k_);            
    x_2_k = x_2_k_ * (1-       K_k_2) + K_k_2 *(sim_y_last(i) - g(i) * x_1_k_); 
    
    % P = (1-Kg)*P_;
    P_k_11 = (1- g(i) * K_k_1)* P_k_pie_11 - K_k_1 * P_k_pie_21;
    P_k_12 = (1- g(i) * K_k_1)* P_k_pie_12 - K_k_1 * P_k_pie_22;
    P_k_21 = (-g(i) * K_k_2 *P_k_pie_11) + (1-K_k_2 ) * P_k_pie_21;
    P_k_22 = (-g(i) * K_k_2 *P_k_pie_12) + (1-K_k_2 ) * P_k_pie_22;
    
    % store data
    data_x1(i) = x_1_k;
    data_x2(i) = x_2_k;
    data_kg(i) =  K_k_1;
    data_p11(i) = P_k_11;
    
end


hold on                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
plot(x,data_x1,'LineWidth',2, 'Color','r');    %x1, square wave 
legend('before','after')

figure
plot(x,data_x1,'LineWidth',2 );    % 
legend('x1')

figure
plot(x,data_x2,'LineWidth',2 );    % background,x2
legend('x2')

figure
plot(x,data_kg,'LineWidth',2);    % kg,Kalman gain
legend('kg')

figure
plot(x,data_p11,'LineWidth',2);    %
legend('p11')
```

In fact, the Kalman gain is a periodic variation rather than a fixed value of convergence.
[image: kalman gain]
and the amplitude of x1 is only half of the theoretical value (The other half is in x2).
[image: x1]
could you please tell me what's wrong with my model? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please edit your question to express your model **in math**, not in Matlab code (or any other computing language).  It will be far more succinct and clear.  Leave in your Matlab code -- there's a good chance that if your underlying model is correct, your Matlab code is in error.  If you can't do it in Latex, take a picture of your notebook where you've written it out and post the picture.

Comment: "process a pulse signal" What do you mean by "process"? What's your goal?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have fixed my problem. Can you see if my model is accurate?

Comment: "process" and "goal" is "Extract a signal from data that is drowned out by noise"

Comment: The Kalman filter equations can be very nicely expressed in matrix notation, and Matlab is most efficient when you leave things vectorized in matrices.  Why are you "unwinding" the filter math?  Have you tried it with the more textbook method?